# MultiSelectList displaying only one selected value out of Selectedvalues

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

For httppost method MultiSelectList shows only one value in view side.

My view

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
   <select class="form-control selectpicker" required="" asp-for="DomID" asp-items=" ViewBag.DomList as MultiSelectList" multiple data-live-search="true"
                                                    placeholder="Select Categories"
                                                    onchange="console.log($(this).children(':selected').length)">
   </select>
</div>
```

MY Controller

```
[HttpPost] 
 public IActionResult controllerAction([Bind]LogModel logmodel)  
{ 
    logmodel.selectedvals=  // Has Submitted/selected values 
    List<LogModel> domList = new List<LogModel>();
    domList = ;//getting values for dropdown
    ViewBag.DomList = new MultiSelectList(domList , "DomID", "Dom", logmodel.selectedvals);
    return view(logmodel);
 }
```

My dropdown shows only one value selected from out of all selected values i.e.. from
logmodel.selectedvals in post action.

If I set hardcode selected values in httpget method for multiselectlist then it's shows
selected  values properly. What I'm doing wrong here?

Updated

```
Log Model
 public Int64 DomID { get; set; }
 public string Dom { get; set; }
 public List<Int64> selectedvals { get; set; }
```

Comment: What's the value of your  ViewBag.DomList ? Could  you share your logModel?

Comment: my dropdown list data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove  `logmodel`  from `return view(logmodel);`

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it , hope it can help.

In Controller:

```
public IActionResult SetList()
        {
            return View(); 
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ShowMList(LogModel logmodel)
        {
            List<LogModel> domList = new List<LogModel>();

            domList.Add(new LogModel() { DomID = 1, Dom = "AA" });
            domList.Add(new LogModel() { DomID = 2, Dom = "BB" });
            domList.Add(new LogModel() { DomID = 3, Dom = "CC" });
            ViewBag.DomList = new MultiSelectList(domList, "DomID", "Dom", logmodel.selectedvals);
            return View();
        }
```

SetList.cshtml:

```
@model LogModel
<form asp-action="ShowMList">
    <select name="selectedvals" class="form-control" multiple>
        <option value="1">AA</option>
        <option value="2">BB</option>
        <option value="3">CC</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

ShowMList.cshtml:

```
@model LogModel

<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" required="" asp-for="DomID" asp-items=" ViewBag.DomList as MultiSelectList" multiple data-live-search="true"
            placeholder="Select Categories"
            onchange="console.log($(this).children(':selected').length)">
    </select>
</div>
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In aspfor `int` I was using int instead of `<int>`